# How do I treat a char as a string in this question?

Tags: c++

Hello I am doing the leetcode problem in C++ called Interger to Roman and here is my following code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    string intToRoman(int num) {
        map<char,int> mp ={
            {'I', 1},
            {'IV', 4},
            {'V', 5},
            {'IX', 9 },
            {'X', 10},
            {'XL', 40},
            {'L', 50},
            {'XC', 90},
            {'C', 100},
            {'CD', 400},
            {'D', 500},
            {'CM', 900},
            {'M', 1000}
        };
        
        string roman = "";
        //iterating from the bottom of the map
        for(auto it= mp.rbegin(); it!= mp.rend(); it++){
            char ch = it->first;
            int val = it->second;
            
            if((num/val) > 0){
                //this is giving us how many times the string/char of the roman
                //will be used
                int count = num/val;
                string to_add(count,ch);
                roman = roman + to_add;
                num = num%val;    
            }
        }
        return roman;
    }
};
```

I would really appreicitate if you could tell me what is wrong with the code. It passes for the value 3 but fails for eg. 58

Comment: Time to use a debugger! Have you tried debugging the program? You can add `cout`s or use a debugger and find the problem.

Comment: Keep in mind that `'example'` is a _multicharacter literal_, whereas `"example"` would be a (const) `char*` that can be stored via `std::string`. Also, if the purpose is to map input numbers to their roman numerals, you likely want a `map<int, std::string>` (i.e. reversing the mapping direction), since you could then gather the roman numerals for a given input number.

Comment: A single char is a single char, is a single char, ... Period!

Comment: So is there no way to treat a char as a string?

Comment: Sure, you could treat it as a `char*` (a c-string), which you could `strcpy` into a valid c-string (with a null terminator), and then construct into `std::string`. But it would probably be much easier to just treat them as a string in the first place (e.g. `"XL").

Comment: @Rogue could you use my code as a small example? I am not sure I follow. The reason is 'L' would just be a char right?

Comment: I'm just saying to replace the single quotes (`'XL'`) with double-quotes (`"XL"`), which will make them a `char*` as opposed to a `char`. These can still be referenced as a `char` for individual characters within the string (e.g. `ch[0]` or `*ch` is the first character, `ch[1]` the second character, etc), but it would be best to use `strcmp`/`strcat` for putting them together. I would do a little more research on [how c-strings are stored](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte).

Answer (score 0):

a better approach is to accualy emulate what roman numbers are formed:

- 1-3 -> add 1 (same group)
- 4 -> sub 1 form 5 (next group - current group)
- 5-8 -> add 1 at 5 and so on

try to figure out a pattern (btw its always 1 added to prev catttergory) so a recursive function will work? or make a calculator for adding 1 until the number is done